# Laravel 5.4 Keeps Logging user out

Tags: php, session, authentication, laravel-5.4

After anytime I move between pages or reload the same page it logs the user out. It worked fine in 5.2 but when I upgraded to 5.4 this problem appeared. I don't know what to provide because I just used:

```
php artisan make:Auth
```

and made my front end the way I wanted it. It is connected to my database remotely and it works because if I put in bad information it does not work. When it logs me in it redirects me, I see my

```
{{Auth:check()}}
```

working fine because I see new links that weren't there when I wasn't logged in. However, anytime I move between any of my pages my naviagation bar goes back to if the user wasn't logged in. It seems as if it is not carrying the session information between pages.

Comment: What is the value in your `.env` for `SESSION_DRIVER`?

Comment: SESSION_DRIVER=database

Comment: I am working on an old laravel 4.2 site, and I am getting a similar issue actually. Looking into it.